# How do I make a top down view with the ability to rotate with built in java graphics?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, java-2d

I'm trying to make a racing game with the top down view on a static player in the middle of the screen, so instead of moving the player through the map, the map would move around the player. Since it's a racing game, I wanted it to also be somewhat similar to a car, but I've been having trouble with rotating the map around the player and having that work with translations.

I've tried keeping track of the center by adding or subtracting from it, which is what I did for the translations, but it doesn't work with the rotate method. The rotate function wouldn't rotate about the player and instead would rotate the player around some other point, and the translations would snap to a different location from the rotations. I'm sure my approach is flawed, and I have read about layers and such, but I'm not sure what I can do with them or how to use them. Also, any recommendations as to how to use java graphics in general would be greatly appreciated!

This is what I have in my main:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;

public class game 
{
    public static void main(String []args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final int FRAME_WIDTH = 1000;
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 600;
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final Map b = new Map();
        frame.add(b,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        b.startAnimation();
    }
}
```

And this is the class that handles all the graphics

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Map extends JComponent implements Runnable, KeyListener
{   
    private int speed = 5;
    private int xcenter = 500; // starts on player
    private int ycenter = 300;
    private double angle = 0.0;
    
    private int[] xcords = {xcenter+10, xcenter, xcenter+20};
    private int[] ycords = {ycenter-10, ycenter+20, ycenter+20};
    
    private boolean moveNorth = false;
    private boolean moveEast = false;
    private boolean moveSouth = false;
    private boolean moveWest = false;

    public Map()
    {
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }
    
    public void startAnimation()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }
    
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.fillPolygon(xcords, ycords, 3);

        // move screen
        if(moveNorth)
        {
            ycenter += speed;
            g.translate(xcenter, ycenter);
        }
        
        else if(moveEast)
        {
            angle += ((1 * Math.PI/180) % (2 * Math.PI));
            ((Graphics2D) g).rotate(angle, 0, 0);
        }
        
        else if(moveSouth)
        {
            System.out.println(xcenter + ", " + ycenter);
            ycenter -= speed;
            ((Graphics2D) g).rotate(angle, 0, 0);
            g.translate(xcenter, ycenter);
        }
        
        else if(moveWest)
        {
            angle -= Math.toRadians(1) % (2 * Math.PI);
            ((Graphics2D) g).rotate(angle, 0, 0);
        }
        for(int i = -10; i < 21; i++)
        {
            g.drawLine(i * 50, -1000, i * 50, 1000);
            g.drawLine(-1000, i * 50, 1000, i * 50);
        }
        g.drawOval(0, 0, 35, 35);

    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if(moveNorth || moveEast || moveSouth || moveWest)
                {
                    repaint();
                }
                Thread.sleep(10);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
            
            }
        }
    }
    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == 68) // d
        {
            moveEast = true;
        }
        
        else if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == 87) // w
        {
            moveNorth = true;
        }
        
        else if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == 65) // a
        {
            moveWest = true;
        }
        
        else if(e.getExtendedKeyCode() == 83) // s
        {
            moveSouth = true;
        }
        
    }
    
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        moveNorth = false;
        moveEast = false;
        moveSouth = false;
        moveWest = false;
    }
    
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: You have be careful with translations, when you translate a `Graphics` context, all following operations are effected by it. Also, Swing is not thread safe, so you shouldn't be using a `Thread` for your main loop and instead you should be using a Swing `Timer`.  You should also be calling `super.paintComponent`

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm sorry, I don't quite understand what it means to have the following operations effected by the translation. Could you give me an example?

Comment: If you translate the `Graphics` context, ie position or rotation, all following operations will be effected by those operations.  If you apply another translation, it will be applied on top of the existing operations, ie, if you apply a 45 degree rotation, draw stuff and then apply another 45 degree rotation, all following operations will be rotate by a total of 90 degrees

Comment: Given the points of @MadProgrammer, I would typically grab the transform (and reference in a local variable) of the `Graphics` object before doing any transformations on the transform of the graphics, just to use to *reset* the graphics object to its original transform for subsequent painting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that transformations are compounding, so if you rotate the `Graphics` context by 45 degrees, everything painted after it will be rotated 45 degrees (around the point of rotation), if you rotate it again by 45 degrees, everything painted after it will be rotated a total of 90 degrees.

If you want to paint additional content after a transformation, then you either need to undo the transformation, or, preferably, take a snapshot of the `Graphics` context and dispose of it (the snapshot) when you're done.

You also need to beware of the point of rotation, `Graphics2D#rotate(double)` will rotate the `Graphics` around the point of origin (ie `0x0`), which may not be desirable.  You can change this by either changing the origin point (ie translate) or using `Graphics2D#rotate(double, double, double)`, which allows you to define the point of rotation.

For example...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        enum Direction {
            LEFT, RIGHT;
        }

        protected enum InputAction {
            PRESSED_LEFT, PRESSED_RIGHT, RELEASED_LEFT, RELEASED_RIGHT
        }

        private BufferedImage car;
        private BufferedImage road;

        private Set<Direction> directions = new TreeSet<>();

        private double directionOfRotation = 0;

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            car = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Car.png"));
            road = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/images/Road.png"));

            InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
            ActionMap am = getActionMap();

            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, false), InputAction.PRESSED_LEFT);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT, 0, true), InputAction.RELEASED_LEFT);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, false), InputAction.PRESSED_RIGHT);
            im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT, 0, true), InputAction.RELEASED_RIGHT);

            am.put(InputAction.PRESSED_LEFT, new DirectionAction(Direction.LEFT, true));
            am.put(InputAction.RELEASED_LEFT, new DirectionAction(Direction.LEFT, false));
            am.put(InputAction.PRESSED_RIGHT, new DirectionAction(Direction.RIGHT, true));
            am.put(InputAction.RELEASED_RIGHT, new DirectionAction(Direction.RIGHT, false));

            Timer timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (directions.contains(Direction.RIGHT)) {
                        directionOfRotation += 1;
                    } else if (directions.contains(Direction.LEFT)) {
                        directionOfRotation -= 1;
                    }

                    // No doughnuts for you :P
                    if (directionOfRotation > 180) {
                        directionOfRotation = 180;
                    } else if (directionOfRotation < -180) {
                        directionOfRotation = -180;
                    }

                    repaint();
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        protected void setDirectionActive(Direction direction, boolean active) {
            if (active) {
                directions.add(direction);
            } else {
                directions.remove(direction);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(213, 216);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            drawRoadSurface(g2d);
            drawCar(g2d);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void drawCar(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            int x = (getWidth() - car.getWidth()) / 2;
            int y = (getHeight() - car.getHeight()) / 2;
            g2d.drawImage(car, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected void drawRoadSurface(Graphics2D g2d) {
            g2d = (Graphics2D) g2d.create();
            // This sets the point of rotation at the center of the window
            int midX = getWidth() / 2;
            int midY = getHeight() / 2;
            g2d.rotate(Math.toRadians(directionOfRotation), midX, midY);
            // We then need to offset the top/left corner so that what 
            // we want draw appears to be in the center of the window,
            // and thus will be rotated around it's center
            int x = midX - (road.getWidth() / 2);
            int y = midY - (road.getHeight() / 2);
            g2d.drawImage(road, x, y, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }

        protected class DirectionAction extends AbstractAction {

            private Direction direction;
            private boolean active;

            public DirectionAction(Direction direction, boolean active) {
                this.direction = direction;
                this.active = active;
            }

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                setDirectionActive(direction, active);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I managed to figure out how to rotate the camera around the player, but I'm still unable to use translations and rotations together to get my desired movement. After rotating, if I translate the map to move up/down, it jumps to a different position than it was at. I think this may be because of the way I keep track of the center (by adding to the x/y coords and translating there), but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Never mind, just fixed it! Thanks for your help!